# Remove quotes from array beginning & trailing

Tags: javascript, arrays

How to remove the leading & trailing double quotes outside the array.

```
var data = [{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }];  
alert(data[0].name)
```

Comment: var data = "[{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }]";
data = data.replace(/(^")|("$)/g, "");
alert(data[0].name)

Comment: You seem to have problems to include code in your question. Have a a look at http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code

Comment: I added my code in the below link http://jsfiddle.net/H2yN6/190/

Comment: And what good is it there? Questions should be self contained. Do we really have to open a link for two lines of code? Other issues: The code you had in the fiddle is different from the on in your comment, so what is it now?

Comment: Code should be in the question. Links can be broken.

Comment: Also, I don't understand the question?

Comment: The code in your question works fine. *What* is your question?

Comment: My hidden input in jsp is having the value like this  "[{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }]". I need to remove the leading & trailing double quotes & my output should like [{"name":"myName" ,"address": "myAddress" }]..Please help.

Comment: Look into the JavaScript `substring()` function.

Comment: Either that or you need to use `var obj = JSON.parse(data);`

Comment: @Phylogenesis Good point. Most likely the OP is trying to convert this into an object.

Comment: I think you have to more specific and provide a concrete example. Does the value *literally* contain the leading and trailing quotes? Or are those maybe just the delimiters of the HTML attribute? Keep in mind that the values of input elements are always strings. The leading and trailing `"` of a string literal or HTML attribute value are *not* part of the string value. You can't replace what doesn't exist (and even then you would still have a string). So, I think you are approaching the issue in the wrong way and you should provide a complete picture of the original issue instead.

Comment: Thank You  Phylogenesis.. var obj = JSON.parse(data); Its working now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to convert a string representation of JSON data into an Javascript object:
http://jsfiddle.net/H2yN6/191/

```
var str = "[{\"name\":\"myName\" ,\"address\": \"myAddress\" }]";
var data = JSON.parse(str);
alert(data[0].name);
```

But if you really do want to remove some leading and/or trailing characters, you can use `substring()`:
http://jsfiddle.net/H2yN6/193/

```
var str = "\"[{\"name\":\"myName\" ,\"address\": \"myAddress\" }]\"";
var str2 = str.substring(1, str.length - 1);
alert(str2);
```